# Expected value bound using high probability bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a random variable $X$, and a high probability bound of the form:
$$P(X\geq f(\delta))<\delta$$
where $f$ is a positive function in $\delta>0$. In general, how can I use this to bound the expected value of $X$?

We know that
\begin{align*}
E[X]\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X\geq x) dx
=\int_{0}^{f(\delta)} P(X\geq x) dx+\int_{f(\delta)}^{\infty} P(X\geq x) dx\\
\leq f(\delta)+\int_{f(\delta)}^{\infty} P(X\geq x) dx
\end{align*}
However, this is as far as I have gotten....

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: What type of bound are you looking for?

Comment: A finite upper bound using $\delta$ if possible

Comment: I'm not certain that the condition is enough to imply that $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$, actually.

Comment: But can we bound just $X$ above? (Not the absolute value)

Comment: I don't know. The given condition $\mathbb P(X\geqslant f(\delta))<\delta$ for all $\delta>0$ may or may not be sufficient for the expectation to be finite. There may need to be additional assumptions on $f$, beyond $f\geqslant 0$.